# Onclick colorbox results Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function after clicking it twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Quick question. I've looked around on here but none actually fixed my issue. The issue is as following: Whenever I click the button which opens the Colorbox for the first time, it just opens perfectly fine. Then I close the colorbox and decide to click on it again. This time, it's giving me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

**It's about this piece of code:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#pay_ideal', function(){
    $.colorbox({
        width: 500,
        height: 350,
        speed: 350,
        closeButton: false,
        href:"udid-order-overview.php"
    });
});
```

What makes it that I'm getting the error? :')

Comment: are you including jQuery in "udid-order-overview.php" ?

Comment: I think that is the problem, I might be wrong but try removing jquery from that page just to check if it is the real problem .. As I see it, on "udid-order-overview.php" page jquery is being replaced with the new object of jquery declared on your second page, thus removing all the functions you declared in the original page..

Comment: Lol why did I not think of that. I removed it like you said and its working fine now. Thank you! :')

Comment: Thanks @KarimAG., I too got the same issue and removed the jquery used in the second page and it fixed my issue. Thanks once again man.. :)